# How to get updated value outside of the Promise's success scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to access the updated value out site the scope like the following scenario.

```
Var data = [];

var getData = function()
{
    var onSuccess = function(result)
    {
        data = result;
    }
    var onError = function(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    ApiCall().then(onSuccess, onError);

}
 getData();

   console.log(data);
```

Here in the above case data is always coming blank array [] not the updated one. how can i access the updated data outside the scope?

Answer (score 1):

You can't and you shouldn't. You need to synchronize your code if you want it to run asynchronously. You can do this by using the promise chain:

```
    return ApiCall().then(onSuccess, onError);
...
getData().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following - you basically need to return your promise.

```
Var data = [];

var getData = function()
{
    var onSuccess = function(result)
    {
        data = result;
        return data;
    }
    var onError = function(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    return ApiCall().then(onSuccess, onError);

}
 getData().then(function (data) { console.log(data); });
```